# How to implement "Restart conversation from here" in webchat just like in bot emulator?

Tags: web-chat, bot-framework-composer

I am looking to implement a functionality which is same as that of "Restart conversation from here" in WebChat. I did not found anything relevant which addresses my requirement.

Comment: Hi and welcome. Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Can you show some code or other indication of what you have tried so far?

Comment: I am using the sample from https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/06.recomposing-ui/d.plain-ui in which I want to restart conversation from a specific message.

Comment: My next approach is to scavenge through the Bot Emulator Code and find the functionality

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar requirement which I needed to implement. I implemented it like this:

1. Get the token of the conversation and saved it inside the state
2. Pass the token to the WebChat component
3. User clicks "Restart Conversation button" -> Set the token to null
4. React then would take care of it, as it would restart the token fetching process and start a new conversation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am looking for restarting conversation at specific question rather than starting conversation from the start. Could you provide some info on that?

Comment: You can set up a middleware and check when a specific message arrives. Use the official samples from Microsoft on how to implement middlewares: https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/04.api/j.redux-actions. From there you can restart the conversation (using the steps above) after receiving that message.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting a conversation using a conversationId usually restarts from the start unless you specify a watermark. In your case you would need to store the watermark with each save point in the conversation.